# Scala Array object

Tags: scala

How do I define an array that contains an integer and three strings with only 20 elements and fill the integer with zero?

I tried but without success:

```
val a = Array [(Int,String,String,String)].fill(20)(0)
```

Comment: How about `Array.fill(20)((0,"","",""))`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:-

```
 Array.fill(20)((0,"","",""))
```

Answer (score 5):

The fill answers are fine, but it's worth saying here that by the time you are at a 4-tuple, your code clarity would almost certainly be improved with a case class.   This is particularly true since three of your fields are strings, which is going to make it really easy to get confused as to just which field means what.